# После переноса папки с проектом git все файлы отмечены как модифицированные

Tags: git, репозиторий, перенос

В процессе работы потребовалось переустановить систему. В проекте были правки, закоммиченные локально, не отправленные на сервер. Я скопировал рабочую папку с проектами на флешку, затем, после переустановки, вернул все с флешки, но путь до проекта немного изменился, пропал промежуточный сегмент. Команда git status в папке показывает, что модифицированными являются все файлы, при этом git log показывает мои коммиты, а так же сохранились неотслеживаемые файлы. Подскажите, как восстановить сделанное? Я работал с отдельной веткой, не с мастером

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, если ты сделаешь stage всех файлов, те, что не были изменены, исчезнут из списка.

Не уверен про сам консольный гит, в двух разных GUI для него я сталкивался с такой ситуацией и не думаю, что разработчики GUI так независимо накосячили - думаю, гит по какой-то причине считает, что файлы менялись (возможно, по дате?).

Answer (score 0):

Утро вечера мудренее. Просто запушил свои правки и там появилась ветка с моими правками

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/868677)

Comment: git diff показал, что изменились права на все файлы